# Using dataTable to sort by 3 separate columns

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable

I have a txt file I'm reading that looks something like this...

```
Acct |Name     |Date      |Country

11111,FirstLast,01/01/2015,United States
11111,FirstLast,,
11111,,01/01/2015,
22222,FirstLast,02/02/2015,Kuwait
22222,FirstLast,,
22222,,02/02/2015,
33333,FirstLast,02/02/2015,France
33333,FirstLast,,
33333,,02/02/2015,
```

I'm creating a dataTable to fill with this data, and am adding a column called "LINE" to keep track of how many lines of data each account has. I then do a dataView sorting to sort like this:

```
dataView.Sort = "Acct ASC, Line ASC, Country ASC"
```

My output sorts by the acct and line#, but not by the country. So I'm getting this back...

```
Acct |Name     |Date      |Country      |Line

11111,FirstLast,01/01/2015,United States,1
11111,FirstLast,,,2
11111,,01/01/2015,,3
22222,FirstLast,02/02/2015,Kuwait,1
22222,FirstLast,,,2
22222,,02/02/2015,,3
33333,FirstLast,02/02/2015,France,1
33333,FirstLast,,,2
33333,,02/02/2015,,3
```

What I want to get back is this because the main thing is to keep the same acct# records together, while sorting by country ascending...

```
Acct |Name     |Date      |Country      |Line

33333,FirstLast,02/02/2015,France,1
33333,FirstLast,,,2
33333,,02/02/2015,,3
22222,FirstLast,02/02/2015,Kuwait,1
22222,FirstLast,,,2
22222,,02/02/2015,,3
11111,FirstLast,01/01/2015,United States,1
11111,FirstLast,,,2
11111,,01/01/2015,,3
```

I then realized that obviously this isn't working because the account number takes precedence in the sortation.

The big issue is that I have to use .NET 2.0, is there some way I can group these and sort by the country field?

Comment: There is no way to sort by both acct # and by country at the same time after the data has been added to the table. You will either keep all the account numbers together or you are going to keep all the countries together.... You will have to manipulate the list to look for countries in alphabetical order, then to look for individual account numbers, and then add the lines to the table one at a time in the correct order - Ensuring that you stop the user from being able to order the data themselves by clicking on the columns, otherwise that automated order will be undone.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally this type of sorting can be implemented in the display such as GridView/DataGridView by Grouping the fields by *Acct* and then sorting within the groups as *Country Desc, Line Asc*.

If you want it to be sorted within the DataTable then you can accomplish by adding another dummy column to the DataTable.

1. Add another column to the **DataTable** e.g. *Grp1*
2. Sort DataTable by *Acct Asc and Country Desc* (so that country name always comes first and blanks later)
3. Iterate DataTable in a for loop (NOT For Each)
   3.1. If *Country* is empty then set *country = country in previous row* (skip row 0, assuming *country* in row 0 always has a value)
   3.2. Within same loop (*outside and after if block*) set the value of *Grp1* column to *Country - Acct*
4. Now sort your DataTable again by *Grp1* and *Line*

**Putting it all together:**

```
dt1.Columns.Add("Grp1")
dt1.DefaultView.Sort = "Acct Asc, Country Desc"
For i = 0 to dt1.Rows - 1
    If i > 0 AndAlso dt1.Rows(i).Item("Country").ToString.Length = 0 Then
        dt1.Rows(i).Item("Country") = dt1.Rows(i - 1).Item("Country").ToString  
    End If
    dt1.Rows(i).Item("Grp1") = dt1.Rows(i).Item("Country").ToString & " - " & dt1.Rows(i).Item("Acct").ToString  
Next
dt1.DefaultView.Sort = "Grp1 Asc, Line Asc"
```